# What is the relationship between aspect ratio and lift-dependent drag?

Tags: aircraft-design, lift, drag

It has been a long held view that aspect ratio of the wing has a significant role to play in the lift-dependent drag. However, mixed opinions have been expressed on the importance of aspect ratio in reducing lift-dependent drag.
I've read a lot of papers and articles and haven't found an absolute answer! So how does Aspect Ratio really play out with lift-dependent drag?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Does [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/58414/62) help?

Answer (score 0):

Aspect ratio is overrated.

What counts is span loading, i.e. the weight which needs to be supported per unit of span. For more, please read [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/716/what-dictates-the-aspect-ratio-of-an-aircrafts-wing/8797#8797).

Generally, more important than the aspect ratio is the induced drag of a wing which carries a given mass at its center. Now the mass of the wing itself also needs to become small, counterintuitively leading to designs [with higher span and a bell-shaped lift distribution](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/67934/what-is-the-drag-optimized-wing-form-for-given-lift-and-bending-moment/67937#67937).